# How to control a hobby servo via arduino using RViz GUI?

Tags: ros, rviz, servo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04LTE and Arduino UNO. I need to control a hobby servo via arduino using RViz GUI. If I move the scroll bar, the motor should rotate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254391/how-to-control-a-hobby-servo-via-arduino-using-rviz-gui-?/) by [RajashekharVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29294/rajashekharvs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-11

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-08**:
@rajashekharVS have you find the answer or have you done this ?

**Comment by [RajashekharVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29294/rajashekharvs/) on 2018-03-02**:
Yes I have done. But not using ROS !

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-03-05**:
I have Done now Sir @RajashekharVS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Easy job :-)

Use firmata firmware for your arduino ( http://firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page)
and a simple python script using https://github.com/MrYsLab/PyMata

Now you can write a small python-node for ros and enjoy rviz.

I did it the same way for testing my robots.
https://github.com/mockbot/MockBot

Cheers
Christian

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2017-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RajashekharVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29294/rajashekharvs/) on 2017-02-11**:
Can you send me a package with URDF and Arduino code to control one motor ? I am actually bad in programming. Can you please help me ?

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-02-12**:
https://github.com/mockbot/MockBot

Load firmata to your UNO and try this as base for your tests:
https://github.com/mockbot/MockBot/blob/master/mockbot/bin/pymata_move_base.py

**Comment by [RajashekharVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29294/rajashekharvs/) on 2017-02-18**:
I tried but couldn't. Can you send me a package so that it will ease my job ? Thanks in advance !